# Spring Mongo Data connection issues with Mongo Atlas Cluster

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I get this error when trying to query documents from a Mongo Atlas Cluster.

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.' on server cluster0-shard-00-02.ondxs.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:302) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:103) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:435) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
```

And this is the connection URI I'm using for Mongo Driver 3.7 or later.

```
spring.data.mongo.uri=mongodb+srv://hiker-app-admin:Hiker2020@cluster0.ondxs.mongodb.net/trail-serivc?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongo.database=trail-service
```

I'm using OpenJDK 11 and Spring Boot 2.3.3. I've also tried overriding Mongo Driver and it didn't work.

Comment: So what is your driver version?

Comment: As my Spring Boot Starter says, it is 4.0.5

Comment: This is supposed to work. Start with some basic driver tutorials in a clean environment.

Comment: What is the openssl version on this system?

Comment: It seems to be working with Java 8....